# Blank screen after Google+ login in Android and iOS captive portal

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth, google-plus-signin

I've this simply google-plus login page.
When I login from the android chrome browser all works correctly but when I try to login from the Android Captive Portal after the login I see only a blank page on the captive portal and the function onSignIn isn't executed.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script>
        function onSignIn(googleUser) {
          var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
          alert('Name: ' + profile.getName());
          alert('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
          document.getElementById("login").click();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>

    <form name="loginform" action="http://10.10.10.1/login" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="username" value="testwifi">
      <input type="hidden" name="password" value="teswifi">
      <input type="submit" name="login" value="log in" id="login" style="visibility:hidden;">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I have the same problem and it seems that there are no solutions for it. It doesn't fires when successful login.

Comment: Looks like it happens on Android 7+

Answer (score 0):

I've debugged the android when the captive loads
it seems like it fail on this one:

[INFO:CONSOLE(20)] "Uncaught Error: sessionStorage is not available in the current environment.", source: https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/o/1096633630-storagerelay.js (20)